# hive parse string from log

Tags: regex, hive, extract

i'm having a problem when parsing string from log file, this is the case:

```
"skey":"110","scp_id":"OC05","capedge":"3G"
"skey":"140","scp_id":"OC02","capedge":"3G"
"skey":"0","scp_id":"OC01","capedge":"3G"
```

this is our expected output for our table

```
|   skey    |   scp_id  |   capedge |
|   110     |   OC05    |   3G      |
|   140     |   OC02    |   3G      |
|   0       |   OC01    |   3G      |
```

i've tried using parse_url method from https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF but unfortunately our string is not in url format, is there any better approach for this? or do i have to use regexp_extract for this?

thank you,
Galih

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: @BijuPDais Hive, using HQL

Answer (score 0):

You may use a combination of `SPLIT` function and `REGEXP_EXTRACT`

```
select REGEXP_EXTRACT( skey     , ':"(\\w+)"', 1) as skey,
       REGEXP_EXTRACT( scp_id   , ':"(\\w+)"', 1) as scp_id,
       REGEXP_EXTRACT( capedge  , ':"(\\w+)"', 1) as capedge 
       from (
              select SPLIT(log_record, ',' )[0]  as skey,
                     SPLIT(log_record , ',')[1]  as scp_id,
                     SPLIT( log_record , ',')[2] as capedge 
                    FROM yourtable
              )  a;
```

[**HUE DEMO**](http://demo.gethue.com/hue/editor?editor=153045&type=hive)  : user id,pwd : *demo,demo*

Comment: hi, your solution runs, but it only returned 1 row, (as i've tried in hue it only returned 1 row) , thanks

Comment: @galih : In Hue i showed you only an example for the first row. Refer to my query above. You need to select from your table a column `log_record` ,which contains those records. I hope you have your log file records loaded as rows in your table.